# How to change for select change in ajax generated select list

Tags: jquery, select

I have `<select id="someid"></select>`

I then click something and jquery.ajax generates new div and attach .html(data) to #someid select. How do I check for change in select?

The reason why I am asking is that I start with empty selects and load them with data related to one record.

There are two selects, select1 and select2. I generate select1 just once and based on selected option from select1 then I generate select2. I need to track if select1 has not been changed and whether I need to regenerate select2. Currently it doesnt do anything $("#select1").change(alert('test')) starts immediately after running the page but wont do anything after another change. It just wont run.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Think you've messed up the code formatting in your Q

Comment: Your jQuery.ajax returns a div element to to attach a select? I think you need to attach option elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ive read the question right, this is very easy using `.change()`

```
$('select#someid').live('change', function() {
  // you code
});
```

Comment: i edited my original question, it just wont run after dynamically loading selects.